# Error al pasar palabras con acentos a un string C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++20

(todo el código está escrito en VS community 2019, en C++20 y ejecutado con la consola del mismo VS)

Tengo un código donde necesito leer de un fichero con palabras varias, pero, a pesar de haber puesto un:

```
#include <Windows.h>
SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
SetCOnsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

Me sigue fallando la lectura al momento de pasar letras con acentos a un string:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me lee bien los acentos que imprimo por pantalla ya existentes, pero cuando hago uso del selector de letras falla:

```
void letras(string& word, string& charG, vector<string>& maxW, vector<string>& otherW) {        //Setea las letras a usar en base a una palabra aleatoria (y, en caso de necesitarlo, usa otra palabra aleatoria más)
    randomize(maxW, word);
    cout << word << endl;
    int i = 1;
    auto it = word.begin();
    bool exist = false;
    charG.push_back(word[word.size() / 2]);
    while (i < 7) {
        for (auto j = charG.begin(); j < charG.end(); j++) {
            if (*it == *j) {
                exist = true;
            }
        }
        if (!exist) {
            charG.push_back(*it);
            i++;
        }
        exist = false;
        it++;
        if (it == word.end() && i < 7) {
            randomize(otherW, word);
            it = word.begin();
            cout << word << endl;
        }
    }
    for (auto j = charG.begin(); j < charG.end(); j++) {
        cout << *j << endl;
    }
}
```

Alguien sabe a qué se puede deber exactamente? He probado todo tipo de formas de poner los acentos y solo me funciona el CP_UTF8 y usar el system("chcp 65001"). Si se necesita más información la paso sin problema, gracias.

Comment: No me queda claro el problema. En otras respuestas expliqué cómo mostrar en y obtener caracteres especiales de la consola. Cuando ya tienes un archivo con texto UTF-8 no hay inconvenientes para obtenerlo e imprimirlo en la consola. Solo tienes que cambiar el CP de salida. Así puedes imprimir texto UTF-8 con `cout`, `printf` o `WriteConsoleA`. Se complica cuando quieres obtenerlo o si deseas imprimir un literal UTF-8 en el código fuente.

Comment: Podría no servir de demasiado, pero puedes forzar al compilador a usar UTF-8 en los strings, [como lo hace drogon](https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon/blob/e640cc092db2d7bc78774002c19cd5d82f951127/CMakeLists.txt#L46), el ejemplo está en CMake pero para Visual Studio puedes irte a `Proyecto -> Propiedades -> C/C++ -> Línea de Comandos -> Opciones adicionales` y ahí escribes `/utf-8`